# LSTM for sequence to output in Keras

Tags: python, keras, sequence, lstm

I'm really confused of how to solve/structure my task using an LSTM from keras:

So I have a `sequence` of `vectors`. Each sequence belongs to a certain output (a document in my case).

The vectors themself are 500 features long (they represent a sentence).

The sequence (how many sentences within a document) varies.. so I assume the sequence needs to be padded, so each sequence is equally long, e.g. say lets make each 200 vectors long.

Now, since each `sequence`belongs to a certain output/ document (1 - 10.000), how do I frame my task?

`Keras`takes an input as `(#samples, time_steps, input_dim)`; so I guess it must be `(#documents, #sentences, #features_of_each_sentece)` - in my case: `(10.000, 200, 500)`

Correct?

**So how do I train my model, to predict which sentence most likely belongs to which document?**

Is my output-vector one-hot-encoded [1, 0, ...] for the first document, [0, 1, ..] sencond etc.? Or is my output-vector just `[1, 1, 1, ...., 2, 2, 2,...]`, so I have just one output vector that contains which sequence belongs to which document??

I'm really confused.. In the end I want to take the last layer to have a vector representation for each document.

so it looks something like:
[image]

Would it be like (?):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(10000,200,500)))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorial_crossentropy',opitimizer=some_optimizer)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first layer of your model is a recurring layer you don't have to specify the length. You can then use masking to work with the varying sequence size.
For more information on Keras Recurrent layers(includes LSTM) check [the documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/)
For a simple example on LSTM's you can look [here](https://keras.io/examples/imdb_lstm/)